# I cannot create a md5-hash code with T-SQL like in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql, hash, md5

I'm posting data to a web service.

But before I send the data to the web service, I have to get the md5-hash code and add it to the soap data.

For the code in `@sendData`, I am expected to generate the md5-hash code

```
58a457d0b2e566048e0a2a046bd68045
```

```
declare @sendData varchar(max)='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'

SELECT
    CONVERT(CHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', @sendData), 2) AS 'hashCode'
```

but as a result of this the md5-hash code returned is

```
4D5A74F92C5B7154247AF52AF3FD13D0
```

I tried entering `@sendData` data from many online md5-hash generation sites. T-SQL's hash code seems correct.

When I said you created the hash code incorrectly, they sent me C# code.

But I use classic ASP, Python, SQL Server T-SQL, can I create a hash code like here?

```
    public static string GetMD5Hash(byte[] inputData)
    {
        MD5 md5Hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(inputData);
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The padding mode is different in c# and java/python.  See padding mode at following : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1062276/Same-string-resulting-different-message-digest-MD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is caused by the fact that the C# code is not hashing the string itself, it is hashing the binary value that is encoded in base64 as that string.

```
string inputString = "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";
//byte[] inputData=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString);
byte[] inputData = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString);
Console.WriteLine(GetMD5Hash(inputData));
```

To do the same thing in T-SQL, you can use something like this:

```
declare @sendData varchar(max)='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'
DECLARE @binaryData VARBINARY(MAX)=(SELECT CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("BASE64_COLUMN"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') FROM (SELECT @sendData AS BASE64_COLUMN) x)
--SELECT CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@binaryData))
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5',@binaryData),2) as 'hashCode'
```